# JsonArrayRequest in android studio project

Tags: java, android, json

here shown in the exception at the `onErrorResponse()`, output like string can't be converted into JSONArray, how can i fix that error

```
try {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new JSONArray(requestS),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR : "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };queue.add(jsonArrayRequest); }catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

Comment: Here is the nice article to read about [JSON marshaling/unmarshaling](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-json-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add new `Response.ErrorListener()`  in `JsonArrayRequest` and put code in try catch:

```
String request = "[{\"course\":\""+COURSE_ID[position - 1]+"\"}]";
        try {


            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url, new JSONArray(request),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                /**
                 * Passing some request headers
                 */
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i am also added the error response listener, but the error shown in Not a primitive array in JSON Array of getting elements from server, i can't understand that error.